# Java Generic Type flexibility with subtype assignment

Tags: java, generics

I have the following structure. A parent class:

```
public class MyTree<E extends MyTree<E>>{
   List<E> children;

   public MyTree(List<E> ls){
      this.children = ls;
   }
   
   public void insert(E t){
     this.children.add(t);
   }
}
```

a child class:

```
public class SpecTree<E> extends MyTree<SpecTree<E>>{
   private E value;

   public SpecTree(E value){
      super(new ArrayList<>());
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

Now from main, I want to insert a tree into another tree.

```
SpecTree<Number> st = new SpecTree<>(0);
st.insert(new SpecTree<Integer>(2));      //incompatible type error
```

The `SpecTree` must be able to accept new children with values that are subtype of the current tree. For example, I should be able to insert a  `SpecTree<Integer>` into `SpecTree<Number>`.

Is it possible to do without changing the structure of code and changing only the type parameters?

Comment: @sweeper I still get the incompatible type error.

Comment: Oops I misread your code. You'd need `class MyTree<E extends MyTree<? extends E>>` and `class SpecTree<E> extends MyTree<SpecTree<? extends E>>`. Does that constitute "changing the structure of code"?

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem. Maybe you just add this as an answer and I mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `insert` expects `SpecTree<Number>`, but we are giving it `SpecTree<Integer>`.

According to [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/5133585), `insert` would be able to take both `SpecTree<Number>` and `SpecTree<Integer>` if it had took a `SpecTree<? extends Number>`. A producer of integers is a consumer of numbers.

That means changing `E` to `SpecTree<? extends E>`:

```
public void insert(E t)
```

Therefore:

```
class SpecTree<E> extends MyTree<SpecTree<? extends E>>
```

However, now the type argument `SpecTree<? extends E>` does not fit the bound specified in `MyTree`, which is `E extends MyTree<T>`, so we change that too:

```
class MyTree<E extends MyTree<? extends E>>
```